# Multitask classification with softmax function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, softmax

I'm trying to train a multi-task classification neural network using softmax as output function.

The idea comes from the paper "Beyond the hype: deep neural networks outperform established methods using a ChEMBL bioactivity benchmark set", where the authors described a MT-NN with 3 hidden layers ([4000,2000,1000]) and ONE output layer with as many nodes as the number of tasks (i.e. 1227). The dataset consisted of molecules tested against different protein targets and labels "1" and "0" described them as active/inactive. In addition, one molecule could be classified as active in more than one target.

In the paper the authors used a custom softmax function on the output layer that instead of yielding a vector o probabilities that sum to 1, it gives INDEPENDENT probabilities for each node/task. This is quite odd to me since I learned that the sum of probabilities of softmax function is one.

Here's the code they used as implemented in lassagna:

```
    def custom_softmax(x):
        num_groups = num_outputs # number of tasks
        probabilities = softmax(x[:, 0:2])
        for i in range(2, 2 * num_groups, 2):
            p_y_given_x = softmax(x[:, 2 * i:2 * i + 2])
            probabilities = T.concatenate([probabilities, p_y_given_x], axis=1)
        return probabilities
```

Since they didn't answer my email I'd like to ask if anybody could explain me what is this custom softmax doing. I naively thought a sigmoid function should be used. To me it seems each node on the output layer is being treated independently.

Another thing is how could I implement this on Keras? I tested the above function and it works when I pass a tensor to it but training fails due to wrong shape of the inputs. For instance, my target variable has shape (10000,154) but when I fit the model with batch size 128 it raises and error saying it expected a shape of (128,78).

Original paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13321-017-0232-0

Comment: I think, you are talking about [Multi-label_classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification). Then I support your idea, that sigmoid function should be used. Do you have any special reasons to understand that paper? If not, I would propose you to just proceed with the sigmoid.

Comment: hi @lanenok. Its quite odd because I've seen this implementation elsewhere too! One hidden layer with many nodes + softmax_crossentropy. In addition, when I tried with sigmoid my recall was really low but I had high precision (prob because of class imbalance).

Comment: I agree that sigmoid should be used: See multitask learning by Andrew Ng: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdXfsAr4Gjw

Answer (score 1):

Sigmoid function gives you an activation probability from 0-1 for each activation node, where softmax will give you an activation probability from 0-1 THROUGH THE SUM OF ALL YOUR OUTPUTS. So you are mixing both concepts, your shape mistmatch is probably due to softmax shape = 2, (152/2!=78 you also have some indexes problems with last minibatch size)

Comment: To clarify my message I will add that sigmoid function sum of probalities is 1 for each output (1=p+(1-p)) and for softmax function is 1 for ALL outputs(1=p1+p2...+pn /where n is all the number of outputs)

Comment: To clarify further the answer: Use sigmoid function for each of the output layers that correspond to your number of items/task you want to recognize! Don't use softmax function!